# How to check which class/UIViewController is executing while testing on device on Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Recently I have been working on an old **swift** project built in back in 2015. Its really difficult to find which **ViewController** is executing currently because of the naming convention, usage of really massive storyboard(I feel terrified to even go to the main.storyboard) and various reason like usage of different language. Of course I can find it but it takes long. I was thinking if there is any way like when I run the project on a device and navigate to different page is there any way to see in the console which **ViewController** is executing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a quick way to find what view controller you are on when you are running your app.

1) Launch your app on the device or simulator.
2) Go into Xcode and tap this button:[image]

3) This will open the Debug View Hierarchy.  Click on the phone and you will see all the elements in the top bar.  You can also see a hierarchy on the left-hand side.  In here, you can click down and you will see the name of the view controller  on screen.

Answer (score 3):

Using the debugger after putting a breakpoint where you prefer you can write this and press return.

**Swift 4.x**

```
po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.value(forKey: "_printHierarchy")
```

This method is a private API, thus you cannot use on production code, just use it in debug or from the debugger console.

Comment: Excellent answer, really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to see in debug area for your current viewcontroller named self, you get all information from there open the dropdown and and see you need to put break point in your viewController init method or where you want to debug, However you want to know programatically which is you current viewController you can get it by

```
appDelegate.window.currentViewController()
```

If you need which ViewController is Pushed or presented you can get from the above code but the case will be different if you are using the Slidemenu controller, I mean it is totally depends on how you have started navigation and which navigation controller is currently is use.

Can you briefly describe why you need current ViewController so i can help you further.